# How to update a second ObjectContext with deletions made on first one

Tags: c#, entity-framework, many-to-many

I have a many-to-many relation Patients - PatientDevices - Devices and a basic edmx-model of it (no poco, automatic generation). PatientDevices is generated as an entity, because it has more columns than the foreign keys.

When I create two ObjectContexts and add a new PatientDevice into the first one, the second one has it also. When deleting this relation from the first one, it is still in the second context:

```
var entities1 = new TherapyDatabaseDevEntities();
var entities2 = new TherapyDatabaseDevEntities();

entities1.PatientDevices.AddObject(new PatientDevice
{
    Patient = entities1.Patients.First(),
    Device = entities1.Devices.First()
});
entities1.SaveChanges();

var relation1a = entities1.Patients.First().PatientDevices.ToList();
var relation2a = entities2.Patients.First().PatientDevices.ToList();

entities1.PatientDevices.DeleteObject(entities1.PatientDevices.ToList().Last());
entities1.SaveChanges();

var relation1b = entities1.Patients.First().PatientDevices.ToList();
var relation2b = entities2.Patients.First().PatientDevices.ToList();
```

relation1a and relation2a both have one entry. relation1b has no entry, but relation2b has one entry. Even if working with refreshes before the query:

```
entities2.Refresh(RefreshMode.StoreWins, entities2.Patients);
entities2.Refresh(RefreshMode.StoreWins, entities2.PatientDevices);
entities2.Refresh(RefreshMode.StoreWins, entities2.Devices);
var relation1b = entities1.Patients.First().PatientDevices.ToList();
// still 1 entry
var relation2b = entities2.Patients.First().PatientDevices.ToList();
```

Is there a possibility to bring the second context up to date or do I have to create another ObjectContext?

**Edit**

I found out that if I do this:

```
entities2.Refresh(RefreshMode.StoreWins, entities2.Patients.First().PatientDevices);
```

the relation gets updated properly. It's a pity that without the refresh entities2.PatientDevices does not contain the deleted object anymore, but entities2.Patients.First().PatientDevices still has it.

Is this intended behavior?

Comment: Why do you need two contexts at the same time? This is highly unusual.

Comment: We have a desktop app which lists devices in a list-control (first context) and patient-tabs where you can attach a device to a patient (second context). We have different contexts to undo changes made to a patient (cancel-button) ==> unit of work pattern.

Comment: the Unit of Work pattern is used to persist changes across *multiple repositories*, not *multiple contexts*. You can almost think of 2 contexts as 2 different databases (hypothetically of course - as EF will assume 2 contexts as possibly 2 different servers). Steven is right, what your doing is very unusual - you should be exposing the entites in your context via repositories and use UoW to manage those repositories. Only 1 context is required. Why do you need different contexts to "undo changes". Use the rollback on your transaction scope/UoW.

Comment: Hmm - how do you manage this with just one context: user opens two patient-tabs and changes both. User clicks on save-button of first patient-tab to save the first patient. However, we have just one EF4-ObjectContext, so the second patient will be saved also. The user cannot cancel the changes made to the second patient anymore.

Answer (score 0):

If you must have multiple contexts and work directly with your entities, have a look at the Attach and Detach methods, which as the names suggest are used to associate/dissociate an object from the context it was retrieved from. Note though that these methods only detatch the object you pass as an argument, not associated objects, so you'd probably have to walk through the connected objects detatching each one, which is messy.

```
    var entities1 = new TherapyDatabaseDevEntities();
    var patient1 = entities1.Patients.Single(p => p.Id = 12345);
entities1.Detach(patient1);
//loop through associated entities calling Detach on each

    var entities2 = new TherapyDatabaseDevEntities();
entities2.Attach(patient1);
//loop through associated entities calling Attach on each
```

My preference would be to use viewmodels so that you aren't editing the entities directly, but representations of them. When a user explicitly saves an object, retrieve that object and update the changes from that object only on a fresh context.

```
var entities1 = new TherapyDatabaseDevEntities();
var patient1 = entities1.Patients.Single(p => p.Id = 12345);
```

... dispose of your context, it's no longer needed, and make your changes here

```
var entities2 = new TherapyDatabaseDevEntities();
var patient2 = entities2.Patients.Single(p => p.Id = 12345);

patient2.Property1 = patient1.Property1;
```

... update with other changes (there's ways to make this code cleaner, just showing simplest example)

```
entities2.SaveChanges();
entities2.Dispose();
```

Some reference material on Attach/Detach here - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896271.aspx

Do a search on entity framework context lifetimes, there's a lot of discussion on this subject which might help you decide on a route that suits your needs.

Comment: I've read about context lifetimes and agree to this (http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/gilf/archive/2010/02/07/entity-framework-context-lifetime-best-practices.aspx) opinion that for WPF-apps a per-form-context is best.
I do not think that detach/attach or a wrapper is a good solution. What about changed relations? You have to detach/attach (or update via a wrapper) these entities too. That could get cumbersome or did I misunderstood you?

Comment: No, you're spot on, it is cumbersome. I hit the same issue, and have yet to see a better alternative, hence going with the least bad option I found. You could retrieve the data with no change tracking (MergeOptions or something like that, on the context), but you still have to attach when you go to save (with child elements). I wrote some generic extension methods to do my updating, which makes it a lot neater.

Comment: Also just noticed you said you're using the default objects. Have you looked at using the POCO generator, or Self-Tracking? I use POCO with a slightly customised T4 template, I have no experience with self-tracking whatsoever though but it it would be worth a look, maybe someone who knows more about Self-Tracking will find this and lend their thoughts.

Comment: I use POCO in my real app but to keep things simple, I made this example with the default generated entities. As far as I know are targeting self-tracking entities mainly n-tier apps.